# Does inline-block not respect bottom and right margins?

Tags: css

```css
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
    <p class="pick">hello1</p>
    <p class="pick">hello2</p>
    <p class="pick">hello3</p>
    <div>1234</div>
```

```
body{
display: inline-block;
margin: 100px 10px 10px 90px;
  /* top:    100 px margin */
  /* right:  10 px margin  */
  /* bottom: 10 px margin */
  /* left:   90 px margin  */
}
```

```html
<p>hello</p>
```

Are only top and left margins respected by inline-block elements ?I saw some answers on SO but they seem to be wrong hence double checking by attached snipped code.

Comment: you have nothing after the inline-block element to verify the effect of margin

Comment: please explain with some example code

Comment: if i change top and left margin values i can see changes being reflected in browser

Comment: add more elements to your code

Comment: added more elements to code and feel my question is wrong, pls confirm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for inline-block it doesnt matter

Answer (score 1):

The problem in the question seems to be applying the style to the `body` tag itself not a specific tag like `p` or something.

Comment: i did some research and find that the question I put is wrong

Comment: Good. You can close the question then or add your own answer to it and choose it (yes, you are allowed to, as long as it's a legitimate case not spam).